# Bootstrap grid column doesent drop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn bootstrap 4. I have my page setup as a three column layout, and defined following properties:

Column 1 has: col-sm-9 col-md-8
Column 2 has: col-sm-3 col-md-2 order-sm-first
Column 3 has: col-xs-12 col-md-2

What i think should happen, is that I get a 2 column layout up till 992px wide, but what happens is that i already get a three column layout when the screen is 768

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lucasw89/f9sc02h6/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- My Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <section class="col-sm-9 col-md-8">
                <article>
                    <h2>Why I Went Into the Lake</h2>
                    <img src="./images/lake.jpg" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="col-sm-10">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        </p>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="More..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article>
                    <h2>My Name is NOT Bullwinkle</h2>
                    <img src="./images/elk.jpg" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="col-sm-10">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        </p>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="More..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article>
                    <h2>There's Gotta be a Penguin Up Here Somewhere</h2>
                    <img src="./images/snowboarder.jpg" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="col-sm-10">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat.
                        </p>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="More..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </section>

            <aside class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 order-sm-first">
                    <h4 class="range-title">
                        <b>Mountain Ranges</b>
                    </h4>

                    <div class="range-list">

                        <a href="wasatch-range.html">
                            <img src="./images/range-1.png" />
                            <h4>Wasatch Range</h4>
                        </a>

                        <a href="mummy-range.html">
                            <img src="./images/range-2.png" />
                            <h4>Mummy Range</h4>
                        </a>

                        <a href="front-range.html">
                            <img src="./images/range-3.png" />
                            <h4>Front Range</h4>
                        </a>

                        <a href="sawtooth-range.html">
                            <img src="./images/range-4.png" />
                            <h4>Sawtooth Range</h4>
                        </a>

                        <a href="west-elk-mountains.html">
                            <img src="./images/range-5.png" />
                            <h4>West Elk Mountains</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </aside>

            <aside class="sports-icon-list col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <a href="downhill.html">
                    <img src="./images/icon-downhill.png" alt="Downhill" />
                    <h6>Downhill</h6>
                </a>

                <a href="snowboarding.html">
                    <img src="./images/icon-snowboard.png" alt="Snowboarding" />
                    <h6>Snowboarding</h6>
                </a>

                <a href="bobsled.html">
                    <img src="./images/icon-bobsled.png" alt="Bobsled" />
                    <h6>Bobsled</h6>
                </a>

                <a href="cross-country.html">
                    <img src="./images/icon-cross-country.png" alt="Cross Country" />
                    <h6>Cross Country</h6>
                </a>

                <a href="biathlon.html">
                    <img src="./images/icon-biathlon.png" alt="Biathlon" />
                    <h6>Biathlon</h6>
                </a>
            </aside>

        </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,regular,italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header, footer{
background-color: #333;
color: #ddd;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

aside {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}


/* The Muntain Ranges */
.range-list {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.range-list h4 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    color: darkorange;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.range-list img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 140px;
    max-height: 60px;
}
.range-title {
    color: darkblue;
}

/* Main Content */
article {
    padding: 40px;
}
article img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #777;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
article p {
    font-size: 16px;
}


/* Sports Icons */
.sports-icon-list {
    background-color: #333;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.sports-icon-list a {
    color: white;
}
.sports-icon-list a h6 {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.sports-icon-list img {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
}

.sports-list-top div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.sports-list-top a {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Authos Comment */
/*@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .range-list a {
        display: block;
    }
    .range-list img {
        width: 33%;
        height: 33%;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .range-list h4 {
        display: inline;
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Please provide us a [mcve].

Comment: `.col-md-*` works for vw >= 768, so looks correct to me. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, `.col-md-*` works for vw >= 768, so looks correct to me. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Back to your code, you need to go one level up with the grid classes. Also, in order to make `.order-*` work, you have to use numbers (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)). Try editing your classes as follows:

```
<section class="col-md-9 col-lg-8 order-md-11 order-lg-1">...</section>
<aside class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 order-md-1 order-lg-11">...</aside>
<aside class="sports-icon-list col-xs-12 col-lg-2 order-md-12 order-lg-12">...</aside>
```

Check updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9sc02h6/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got confused with the levels.